# QGraphicScene Background

Tags: python, pyqt, background, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene

I'm learning PyQt5 to develop a small academy project. I need to set a background for the QGraphicScene, but I'm not able to make the image fit well into the scene. It is sometimes repeaded or too large depending on the scale I apply. Here is my code:

```
class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "title";
        self.top = 100
        self.left = 100
        self.width = 1500
        self.height = 900
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, width, heigth)
        view  = QGraphicsView(scene, self)
        image = QImage('pathToImage')
        scene.setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(image))

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.top, self.left, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()
```

I've tried to rescale the image with

```
image.scaled(scene.width(), scene.height(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
```

but it does not fit well, in fact there are scrollbars because the image is too large.
Anyone knows where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the image to scale then you must override the `drawBackground()` method:

```py
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._image = QImage()

    @property
    def image(self):
        return self._image

    @image.setter
    def image(self, img):
        if img != self.image:
            self._image = img
            self.update()

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        if self.image.isNull():
            super().drawBackground(painter, rect)
        else:
            painter.drawImage(rect, self.image)
```

```
scene = GraphicsScene(self)
scene.image = QImage("pathToImage")
view = QGraphicsView(scene)
```